# Not able to load credentials of an EC2 instance on InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I have attached an EC2 role to the instance , to my EC2 instance and I am running my AWS JAVA SDK . When I am trying to load the credentials this way :

```
InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider instanceCred = new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider();
```

I am getting the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load credentials.
    at com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.loadCredentials(InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.java:195)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.java:124)
```

Can any suggest what I might be missing?

Comment: Are you running this code from inside your ec2 instance? The EC2 metadata api(which is used internally by InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider)  is only available for calls from within the instance, not from the outside world.

Comment: I have hit the same problem running on an EC2 instance that has an explicit IAM role that provides access to the needed resource. Any update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get around it by running the code from my EC2 instance and enhancing my code , here is the code :

```
 String arn = "arn:aws:iam::"+accountnumber+":role/My-CrossAccount-CustomRole-ReadOnly";

InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider instanceCred = new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider();

stscred = new STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider(instanceCred.getCredentials(),arn,"123",clientConfiguration);
```

Make sure you have `"sts:AssumeRole"` in your role actions .